# react-native-photo-editor: Add border outside transparent image edges? Or a dark background?

Tags: android, react-native

Using **react-native-photo-editor**, when typing text over a transparent image, I don't see the edges of the image, so after moving and saving, the text is sometimes cut.

Is it possible to add a border around the image itself? Or a darker background (around the transparent image, that doesn't show in the image's background itself)?